# Xcode: throwing a compiler error in the issue navigator

Tags: swift, compiler-errors

I'm working on a UI utility class I would like to publish on github. I would like to know how to throw a compiler error in the issue navigator. I should stress that this is not about throwing errors at runtime! I would like to signal to the programmer using my utility class that adding a certain property to an object is not allowed when this object is in a certain state. 
I know that I can use assertionFailure("bla bla") in Swift but this would throw an error at runtime.

Comment: Can you describe your problem more concretely? How can an object "be in a certain state" at compile time?

Comment: @kvr: The Swift compiler does not recognize #error/#warning.

Comment: Thanks for the quick replies! I'm creating a View Controller subclass similar to Apple's UIAlertController. Like the original it has two styles: Alert and ActionSheet. I want to prevent that the programmer adds a text field to an Action Sheet, it should only be possible when the style is Alert. Xcode should simply show an error during compiling so that it is not possible to run the code.

Comment: let actionSheet = DYAlertViewController(style: .actionSheet, title: "Doing stuff", titleIconImage: titleImage, message:"Select one option", cancelButtonTitle: "Cancel", okButtonTitle: "Do it!",... )                                                             actionSheet.addTextField("Title")         // show show an error on the left side bar   "Can't add a text field to an action sheet"

Comment: OK... I got it. I wasn't aware Apple was facing the same problem. if you add a text field to a UIAlertController, style ActionSheet, the compiler accepts it without complaining but at run time an assertion failure makes the app crash:*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Text fields can only be added to an alert controller of style UIAlertControllerStyleAlert'